# asp:linkbutton inside gridview

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a serverside dropdownlist and I am accessing it's id in jquery like this

$('#<%=ddldropdownlist.clientID%>')

I have a asp:LinkButton inside a gridview and I want to access it's client ID.

when I do as above in jquery it doesn't work

I think that's not the correct way since the server control is inside another server control

Could someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few of options:

The most common would be to assign a custom class or attribute to the button that you can use as a selector.

The other way would be to implement the `OnDataBinding` event for the button and then assign the `ClientID` of the control from the `OnDataBinding` `sender` to your Jquery call in this function for each control assuming you are trying to hookup some Jquery to your button.

You could also use the `OnDataBinding` method to build up a hidden field with a list of `ClientID` names.

The best solution is probably to get a selector working but there are cases where the `OnDataBinding` works great as well.

Answer (score 2):

The *ClientID* of the `LinkButton` is going to get mangled once it's within a repeating control like a `GridView` or a `ListView`.  If you need a way to access the LinkButton you can assign a unique class name to them like "link-thing" and then use that within jQuery like so:

```
$(".link-thing")...
```

Comment: I concur. ASP.NET will tear up the expected clientID's of controls. Using a unique 'class' though will make it easier for jQuery to walk through the DOM and find the items that you're looking for.